# Why Is Private Homepage Not Private via Session/Login Variables

Tags: php, session, redirect

I have a login page that redirects to a private homepage after the user has entered a valid username/login. I've set the homepage to be private through session variables - if the session variables are set (meaning that the user has submitted correct login info) then it's viewable. If the session variables are not set (!isset) that the page SHOULD be private and redirect back to the login page. However, the homepage does not appear private and direct to the login page if the user has not logged in.

LOGIN PAGE PHP & HTML

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once("../inc_files/Lesson_5_DB_Connection.php"); 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

$error_message= "";
$user_name = "";
$user_password= "";
$member_name="";
$member_id="";

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    $user_name = $_POST['user'];
    $user_password= $_POST['pass'];



    // ADD QUERY TO CHECK IF USER/PASS COMBO IS CORRECT
    if(!empty($user_name) && !empty($user_password)) {

        $query = "SELECT * FROM employees WHERE username='$user_name' and password='$user_password'";

        $result = mysqli_query($dbc, $query)
            or die ('Error querying username/password request');

        if(mysqli_num_rows($result) == 1) {

            $_SESSION['member_name'] = $member_name;
            $_SESSION['member_id'] = $member_id;


            header("Location: /LESSON5/3%20-%20HOMEPAGE%20:%20WELCOME.php");
            exit;

        } // end if rows

        else {
            $error_message = "You were not able to log in";
        } // end else

        // Direct to other webpage

    } // end query

} // end isset
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Login</title>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/LESSON5/5_Signup_CSS.css">

    </head>
    <body>
    <h1>Welcome to my website!</h1>
    <h2>Please login below.</h2>
    <h3>Don't have an account? <a href="/LESSON5/2%20-%20CREATE%20AN%20ACCOUNT.php">Create one here.</a></h3>

    <div class="formFormat" >  
    <div  id="table1">
    <form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>">
      <table id="cssTable">
        <tr>
            <td>Username:</td><td><input type="text" id="user" name="user" value="<?php echo $user_name;?>" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Password:</td><td><input type="text" id="pass" name="pass" value="<?php echo $user_password;?>"/></td>
        </tr>
          </table>

      </div>

      <div id="table2">

      <table> 
      <tr>
         <td><input type="submit" name="submit"/></td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
          <td id="createAccount"><a href="/LESSON5/2%20-%20CREATE%20AN%20ACCOUNT.php">Create an account</a></td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
        <td><p><?php echo $error_message?></p></td>
       </tr>

      </table>
      </form>
      </div>
    </div> 

    <?php
      mysqli_close($dbc);
    if(isset($_SESSION['user']) && isset($_SESSION['pass'])) {

    echo "Sessions are set";

    }

    else { 
      echo "Not set.";
    }
    ?>

    </body>
    </html>
```

It seems like the session variables `$_SESSION['member_name'] = $member_name` & `$_SESSION['member_id'] = $member_id` are not being set upon submission in the login page, and I don't know why.

Here, if the session variables are not set (via !isset), the homepage should redirect to the login and not show the homepage. Here, this is not working, assuming because the session variables in the above code are not set, and the homepage is not reading the PHP script properly and making the homepage public.

HOMEPAGE PHP

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once("../inc_files/Lesson_5_DB_Connection.php");

$member_name="";
$member_id="";

if(!isset($_SESSION['member_name']) && !isset($_SESSION['member_id'])) {

    header("Location: /LESSON5/1%20-%20LOGIN.php");
}

?>
```

I know there's an error in the `$_SESSION` variables but I can't figure out where the gap is. Any input on this would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried moving the header stuff to the top before any outputs?

Comment: have you tried printing the session variable using `print_r($_SESSION)` in your home page... and check wether it contains any value or not

Comment: Check your PHP log, make sure it's not logging "Headers already sent".

Comment: use `||` instead of `&&` while checking session variables.. also put `exit` after your header.... in homepage file

Comment: try to print $_SESSION['member_name'] in home page to check if session is assigned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to fetch the results from the query using mysqli_fetch_assoc()

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php

Here is your same code, only with the fetch_assoc() added and assigned to your session variables:

```
    <?php
session_start();
require_once("../inc_files/Lesson_5_DB_Connection.php"); 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

$error_message= "";
$user_name = "";
$user_password= "";
$member_name="";
$member_id="";

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    $user_name = $_POST['user'];
    $user_password= $_POST['pass'];



    // ADD QUERY TO CHECK IF USER/PASS COMBO IS CORRECT
    if(!empty($user_name) && !empty($user_password)) {

        $query = "SELECT * FROM employees WHERE username='$user_name' and password='$user_password'";

        $result = mysqli_query($dbc, $query)
            or die ('Error querying username/password request');

        if(mysqli_num_rows($result) == 1) {

            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                $_SESSION['member_name'] = $row['member_name'];
                $_SESSION['member_id'] = $row['member_id'];
            }

            header("Location: /LESSON5/3%20-%20HOMEPAGE%20:%20WELCOME.php");
            exit;

        } // end if rows

        else {
            $error_message = "You were not able to log in";
        } // end else

        // Direct to other webpage

    } // end query

} // end isset
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Login</title>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/LESSON5/5_Signup_CSS.css">

    </head>
    <body>
    <h1>Welcome to my website!</h1>
    <h2>Please login below.</h2>
    <h3>Don't have an account? <a href="/LESSON5/2%20-%20CREATE%20AN%20ACCOUNT.php">Create one here.</a></h3>

    <div class="formFormat" >  
    <div  id="table1">
    <form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>">
      <table id="cssTable">
        <tr>
            <td>Username:</td><td><input type="text" id="user" name="user" value="<?php echo $user_name;?>" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Password:</td><td><input type="text" id="pass" name="pass" value="<?php echo $user_password;?>"/></td>
        </tr>
          </table>

      </div>

      <div id="table2">

      <table> 
      <tr>
         <td><input type="submit" name="submit"/></td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
          <td id="createAccount"><a href="/LESSON5/2%20-%20CREATE%20AN%20ACCOUNT.php">Create an account</a></td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
        <td><p><?php echo $error_message?></p></td>
       </tr>

      </table>
      </form>
      </div>
    </div> 

    <?php
      mysqli_close($dbc);
    if(isset($_SESSION['user']) && isset($_SESSION['pass'])) {

    echo "Sessions are set";

    }

    else { 
      echo "Not set.";
    }
    ?>

    </body>
    </html>
```

You stated member_name and member_id are not set, this is because you never grabbed their data from the database when you ran your query. You need to fetch the assoc array of your query, and assign them to your session. Since you didn't do this, it used the values you defined at the top, which were empty:

```
$member_name="";
$member_id="";
```

That is why they were empty, because they ARE empty.

There are other things that I see with what you are doing. You have spaces in your file names (ie: the %20), they should be replaced with underscores. While it will work, your causing future headaches for yourself. It looks like your passwords are plaintext. You should be using encrypted passwords as of like, 20 years ago (ie: bCrypt). You really don't need to set the error_reporting or ini_set in your code, it should be configured per your environment in your server config (ie: php.ini). You shouldn't use a wildcard (ie: SELECT *), instead declare the columns you need to work with.

I would also add a LIMIT 1 to the query. Only way you would get more than 1 matching user, is if your have a flaw in your account signup/registration code.

Malicious code could be added to the page since you are echoing the username/password onto the page without sanitizing it.

You are using mysqli, which is a good start, but you are using them un-sanitized in your query. When using data FROM the user, you should be using prepared statements or using mysqli_real_escape_string() first. Just using mysqli doesn't protect you.

In all, you would save yourself a lot of trouble if you would use a framework like [Yii](http://yiiframework.com) - Login and Signup are done for you out of the box, with bcrypt on the passwords, as well as hundreds of other reasons to use a framework :) Yii is just my fav, but any framework would help any programmer. I haven't had to handle sessions or login/register code for a long time...

**ADDED**
Adding more values from table to store in session:

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $_SESSION['member_name'] = $row['member_name'];
    $_SESSION['member_id'] = $row['member_id'];
    // add everything you want from your table
    $_SESSION['employeeId'] = $row['employeeId'];
    $_SESSION['anotherColumn'] = $row['anotherColumn'];
}
```

**Final Thought**

It seems like you have a bit of a mess. I think you need to start over with this php code from scratch. Look at your table in the database, make sure it is as neat and tidy as possible. Column names make sense, and all that.. Then re-make this php file to login.

All you need to do is authenticate the user. You don't need to store everything about the user in the session. PHP itself will kill the session once it expires (they close their browser, or by PHP's default session time limits). A properly configured server would handle the session on it's own just fine. So all you have to do is authenticate them, and store basic data in the session.

After you have confirmed the user and password, just store their user id in the session. Then have a function at the top of each page to get their user data for use on the page:

```
function getUserData($id) {
    $query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = $id LIMIT 1";
    $result = mysqli_query($dbc, $query);
    if ( $result ) {
        if(mysqli_num_rows($result) == 1) {
            $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
            return $row;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

$userData = getUserData($_SESSION['user_id']);
if ( ! $userData ) {
    die('Error: User data not found!');
}

// we have the user data for the rest of the page
echo "ID: $userData['id']";
echo "Username: $userData['username']";
```

Just an example, there may be flaws in my code.. But I hope you get the point. In my example, im only storing the user's id in the session. Then my function (used before anything else in my code) returns that users info into an array. Then you can use $userData array anywhere in the page.

Comment: she is checking the same username and password are there in the db.. and if yes she is assinging the posted value.. no need to fetch

Comment: This is what I'm confused about (I'm modeling this off previous examples)...so we set $_SESSION variables - can the values be anything we want? I have $_SESSION['member_id'] and  $_SESSION['member_name'], but `member_id` and `member_name` are not part of my database and not part of any form field - do these values have to be coming from somewhere or can I just set them as I please?

And yes @Nishant Solanki, I'm just checking the username/password in the database

Comment: @NishantSolanki - Sorry, but you are incorrect. You are too quick to downvote

Comment: I had an array and deleted it - made no difference

Comment: @WadeShuler yeap.. sorry it was an mistake.. she still have to fecth the member_id.. downvote removed... and upvoted for the edit

Comment: @isha if member_id and member_name fields are not present in the database, then you should take `username` and `userid`... you can use any appropriate fields... but it should be unique for each user..

Comment: @Wade Shuler thank you for all the tips. I know the code is inefficient (for now). I'm just trying to get the basics down then add some security measures. I'd love to check out the framework since working directly with PHP is not my favorite thing...anyways

I've set values to the $_SESSION variables (added in name of column $_SESSION['username'] = $row['username']; $_SESSION['employeeNumber'] = $row['employeeNumber'];) and put them in an array using my_fetch_array. In the top of the code I set them to ="". I was getting an error code before and defining them as empty up top helped.

Comment: @Wade Shuler and i updated the HOMEPAGE code to reflect the new variables:  if(!isset($_SESSION['username']) && !isset($_SESSION['employeeNumber']) {header("Location: /LESSON5/1%20-%20LOGIN.php");
 }
However, now the HOMEPAGE comes out blank (no error message from query/connecting to database).Do you know why it could be blank after re-setting the variables as you mentioned in the array?

Comment: My answer is exactly why 'member_id' and 'member_name' are not set in your session, you never set them to anything other than "". You MUST have these column names in your 'employees' table. So given that you have these column names, and you follow my answer, they should be set. So I don't see the issue.. if you need to add more things to the session, then do it right below the 2 lines I added... I will add to my answer in a few seconds.

Comment: You have member_name.. now username.. employeeNumber.. - I think you need to scrap it and start over. To login, you don't need all this data. All you need to do is authenticate the user.. then store basic data in the session (like their user id).. All you really need is their user ID number... Then once inside, you can get all their user info by that ID

Comment: Why are you using a `while` loop to fetch the row from a query that should only return one row? I see this all the time in questions, because they're new and don't know any better, but I'm surprised to see it in an answer.

Comment: @Barmar It was copy-n-pasted off php.net's doc for simplicity at like 1am. You are right, the loop isn't necessary for 1 record, though it is when fetching multiple records. - If you look further down, you can see my "final thought" bit of code isn't using the loop. Complaining about it being in a loop is nit-picking, doesn't degrade performance, and doesn't hurt anything. Especially if you use "LIMIT 1" in your query.  - I use framworks, and haven't had to write this low-level code for a while now. Dealing with sessions and user auth, is a thing of the past for me.

Answer (score 0):

try using reversed.

```
if(isset($_SESSION['member_name']) && isset($_SESSION['member_id'])) {

//your content

}
else
header("Location: /LESSON5/1%20-%20LOGIN.php");
```

Comment: It won't matter because this isn't the problem: When they perform the query to pull the user's information, they are NOT fetching the value from that query using mysqli fetch assoc. They are setting it to the values declared at the top, which is nothing ($member_name="") because they have not been set anywhere.. Look at my answer, where I use fetch assoc after they had `if(mysqli_num_rows($result) == 1) {`